# Chrome stuck in infinite loop, can't copy/paste to save my jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, memory, browser

Hey all I was just putting the finishing touches on a jsfiddle for a fellow StackOverflow user, and I accidentally introduced an infinite loop into my code. Now my page is totally stuck. All I want to do is get the text I have written in the JSFiddle fields out so I don't lose the work I've done. Is there some way to tell Chrome "Hey, abort whatever you're doing so I can scroll around the page and copy text"?

Chrome Version 30.0.1573.2 dev-m

Stuff that doesn't work:

- Click and dragging on the page to select
- Right clicking on the page
- `$('#element').text()` in F12 console
- Expanding the elements in the F12 DOM tree list to copy the child
- Whoops I closed the debugger, now it is simply not repainting that area of the screen, and it doesn't reopen when I hit F12
- Control-U to view source opened a tab the first time, which just hung with a 'loading' favicon
- Now Control-U doesn't do anything

for those interested i believe the looping code was something like

```
function lorem(n){
  var words = ["lorem"]
  while(words.length < n){
    words.concat(words);
  }
  return words.join(' ')
};
```

edit: 
How do you earn this badge? Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months

Comment: I gave up on it and [rewrote the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6WZrM/4/); still curious if anyone knows a way to do this though

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that there is no way to do this.